# replacing selective values in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with 47520 records having 2 columns. "id" and "gap". All gaps are 0 here.
I have another file with fewer records and same columns.
All I want is to update gaps of relevant ids in first file, so that my final file have 47520 records with updated gaps. Below is my code snippet, but it doesn't update my gaps.

```
e = pd.read_csv('sample (3).csv')
edict = dict(zip(data3["gap"], data3["id"]))
e["gap"].replace(edict, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample dummy data so we can see what you'd like to do/easily prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = df1.replace(0, np.nan).set_index('id')
df1.combine_first(df2.set_index('id')).reset_index()
```